# Reputation mis-represented

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation

In http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/identifying-a-dis-accepted-answer/2936#2936 Hendrik mentions that the feature showing which answer was disaccepted is now available.

However the introduction of such feature caused a misrepresntation of reputation:

[image: Reputation mis-calc]

I had [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20%2B20%2B60%2B2%2B50%2B20%2B10%2B15%2B15) agree with me that the reputation is actually **212** and not 197 as shown in the picture. [The reputation page here](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) (which you may not have access to...) log is:

```
 2     65706 (10)
 1     65791 (15)
 2     66013 (10)
 2     65791 (10)
 2     66013 (10)
 2     65791 (10)
 2     66013 (10)
 2     66013 (10)
 2     66080 (10)
 2     66080 (10)
 2     66080 (10)
 1     66013 (15)
 2     66013 (10)
 2     66080 (10)
 2     66080 (10)
 2     40939 (10)
 1     65616 (2)
 2     66080 (10)
 2     40939 (10)
 2     66150 (10)
 2     66150 (10)
-- 2011-09-20 rep +212  = 13625
```

The question from which the dis-accepted answer came from was posted on that same day, so it cannot be that I lost reputation that I gained at any earlier day by that action.

Comment: No one has access to that page but you, pretty much. However, you might consider just posting the snippet for that day in the text here.

Comment: @Grace: Is my testimony not enough as a report on its own accord?

Comment: Oh, I trust it, but extra data is always nice, is all. It's fine if you think it's too much extra work. Took me a while to notice that the issue is that the initial +15 for acceptance isn't displayed, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [was a display bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/when-someone-unaccepts-your-answer-after-initially-accepting-it-it-looks-like-th) in which an accept/unaccept in quick succession showed as a "unaccept" in the reputation tab...when in reality this cancelled out for the day.  This [has since been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/when-someone-unaccepts-your-answer-after-initially-accepting-it-it-looks-like-th/107054#107054), you'll see that [the -15 is no longer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila?tab=reputation).